# Play 2.3 scala forms - how to customise constraint messages

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, constraints, customization

I've created form in play framework with constraints:

```
val voucherForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "voucherName" -> nonEmptyText,
    "voucherCode" -> optional(text(minLength = 6).verifying(pattern("""[a-zA-Z0-9]+""".r, error = "...")))     
  )(VoucherForm.apply)(VoucherForm.unapply)
)
```

when I display this form on a web page I have constraint messages (like `Required`, `Minimum length: 6, constraint.pattern`) shown near input boxes.

I want to customise this constraint messages per input field (i.e. two `nonEmptyText` constraints in same form will have different constraint message). How could I do it?

Answer (score 2):

These messages are taken from, well, messages. You can create your custom messages file and put there your custom text. Navigate through sources to check what is the valid string to put there.

For example `nonEmptyText` is declared as follows:

```
val nonEmptyText: Mapping[String] = text verifying Constraints.nonEmpty
```

and from there, `Constraints.nonEmpty` looks like this:

```
  def nonEmpty: Constraint[String] = Constraint[String]("constraint.required") { o =>
    if (o == null) Invalid(ValidationError("error.required")) else if (o.trim.isEmpty) Invalid(ValidationError("error.required")) else Valid
  }
```

so the error string is `"error.required"`

now you can create a file `messages` in conf directory and put there a line

```
error.required=This field is required
```

`ValidationError` has `apply` method declared like this:

```
def apply(message: String, args: Any*)
```

which means you can also pass arguments there, in `messages` you can access them using `{arg_num}` syntax

If you for example created error like this

```
val format = ???
ValidationError("error.time", someFormat)
```

That will be returned with a bounded form, then play will use `MessagesApi` to find a message named "error.time" and format it accordingly, you could for example create a message like this:

```
error.time=Expected time format is {0}
```

My idea to have a custom message for each field is a custom method like this:

```
  def nonEmptyTextWithError(error: String): Mapping[String] = {
    Forms.text verifying Constraint[String]("constraint.required") { o =>
      if (o == null) Invalid(ValidationError(error)) else if (o.trim.isEmpty) Invalid(ValidationError(error)) else Valid
    }
  }
```

probably not an ideal solution if you want to use many kids of constraints.

Comment: Yeah. But this will provide same message for each input box with nonEmptyText constraint. But what I really need is to customize that error.required code per input box constraint

Comment: then I believe you would need to create your own constraint. Possibly with a helper method, I mean you could rewrite nonEmptyText but make it take an argument that will be put in error message.

Comment: Well, some constraints are quite deeply nested (e.g. `number` constraint). It'll be faster and maybe cleaner to hide constraint messages from template using `'_showConstraints -> false` and to add html element similarly styled with custom message.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using nonEmptyText, could you not use `text`, and put your custom message in the `verifying`, along the lines of:

```
val voucherForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "voucherName" -> text.verifying(
      "Please specify a voucher name", f => f.trim!=""),
...
```